# I am unable to mutate the array in the Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am not able to mutate the array in the initialState(**winArray[ ]**).
Here I am getting the payload from the component level. payload has two values one is id and the other one is value, Here I am using the id as the index at which the value is inserted into the **winArray**.
can anyone please help me in mutating the array in the state?

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState={
winArray:['','','','','','','','','']
}
const gameWinSlice=createSlice({
    name:'gameWin',
    initialState:initialState,
    reducers:{
        winStatus(state,action){
            const id=+action.payload.id
           let temp=[...state.winArray];
            temp[id]=action.payload.value;
            temp.splice(id,0,action.payload.value);
            console.log(state.winArray)
         return{
             ...state,
             winArray:temp
         }
       
        }
    }
});

export const gameWinActions =gameWinSlice.actions
export default gameWinSlice;
```

Answer (score 0):

In createSlice reducers, you can just do

```js
  state.winArray[+action.payload.id]=action.payload.value;
```

Also see [Writing Reducers with immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) in the docs

Comment: Hi, @phry Thank you much !! for responding, but it is not working  ☹️ .

Comment: Are you sure that it's this part that's not working? Have you validated in the Redux Devtools that the action is dispatched and the store is not working?